# In a node script how can I monitor a file for changes and get the updated content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm writing a script to monitor a file. Whenever the file changes it needs to print to the appended content to the console. I'm dabbling with `fs.createReadStream` but it doesn't seem to send anymore data over the stream when the file is appended to. I'm also just plain new to streams in general. Hopefully I just need someone to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: You need to keep current content somewhere. Then watch the file with `fs.watchfile`... Find the diff on change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [node-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch) module:

```
var watch = require('node-watch');

watch('somedir_or_somefile', function(filename) {
    console.log(filename, ' changed.');
});
```

If you are operating under the assumption that the file is only being appended to, you could store the number of bytes read so far in a variable, and then inside your watch callback, use that as the `position` argument for [fs.read](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback).

Comment: Perfect. I'm reading from a log file so it only ever gets appended to. Thanks a ton.